# Put a bar which dont hide elements under - at the bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to place a bar on the bottom of (visible) page.

```
.footer {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      left: 0;
}
```

This class would be nice, but if I minimalize window, bar move and hide my content below it. I want to bar stay under content and wait for maximalize window.

Comment: Sticky footers are tricky. Footers that stick to the end of content have been in developers nightmares for years, and several solutions exists. Generally you'd have to use special markup, and some pretty specific CSS to make it work, positioning an element fixed at `bottom:0` just doesn't do it -> **https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/**

Answer (score 0):

Add an amount of padding-bottom to the parent element of .footer that is equal to the height of .footer.

Comment: Are you sure? It still on the same pos